# How do I detect and control the "location" of focus on a page without directly adding focus to an element?

Tags: javascript, html, focus, accessibility, tabindex

When you first load a web page, then press "Tab", `document.activeElement` will be the `<body>` tag and nothing on the page will have focus (i.e. `$(':focus')` will be empty).

Pressing "Tab" will add focus to the first focusable element on the page (which will become `document.activeElement` and also `$(':focus')`.

If you click somewhere further down the page on a non-focusable element (e.g. text in a `<p>` tag), `document.activeElement` again becomes the `<body>` tag and nothing on the page will have `:focus`, but pressing "Tab" will add focus to the first focusable element after the content that was clicked.

---

**My question is:** is there any way to tell the difference, using JS, between:

- the state on initial page load (where no element has `:focus` but pressing "Tab" adds focus to the first focusable element) and
- the state after clicking some non-focusable element further down the page?

---

For context: I'm building a website where you can click hash links to navigate to different parts of the page and want to animate scrolling to the different parts instead of having them jump immediately. I have everything working, except for focus (right now pressing "Tab" after clicking one of the links just goes to the next link instead of the first focusable element in/after the element I scrolled to). I know I can use `tabindex="-1"` and `element.focus()` to force focus to the section of the page I scrolled to, but I'd rather replicate native browser behavior if possible.